# Why getting 400 Bad Request while sending http request with Socket java class?

Tags: java

I'm tryin' to reach a server and i'm using Socket class. Unfortunately when i send a GET HTTP message to the server, it responses with 400: Bad Request! 
Is it something wrong with my GET message format? 
or problem comes from somewhere else?

Note: i don't want to use any HTTP APIs; just wanna work with Socket

```java
private void createSocket() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket("www.varzesh3.com",80,null,0);
        String httpRequest = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: varzesh3.com\r\n";
        System.out.println(httpRequest.length());
        System.out.println(socket.isConnected());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        java.io.BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din));
        dout.writeUTF(httpRequest);
        System.out.println(dout.size());
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    }
```

Comment: You need an additional `\r\n` at the end since header and body are seperated with two dos-style linebreaks

Comment: `4xx` are a client-side issues. do read https://www.websitepulse.com/kb/http_status_codes

Comment: @f1sh did'nt work. still getting 400 Bad Request